# Is there an easy way to insert logging into a class from dependency?

Tags: java, debugging, maven, intellij-idea

I have some dependency which behaviour looks suspicious. I suppose there is a data race problem in it: one of my calls to the class sets some internal variable to null, while other call is still being processed. This causes an exception.

I want to insert logging into some classes of that dependency to be sure I am right.

The problem is that I cannot modify the sources of that dependency directly. I get them via Maven and can see them in my Idea, but thats all. The only idea I have is to replace that classes with the modified versions via classpath. But probably there is a better way? Can I make a kind of a "hot redeploy" for this?

Comment: If you are not in need of parallel processing you could also synchronize the dispatcher to this non thread safe library.

Comment: There is AOP, which manipulates the byte code, so you can intercept calls and such. A bit of heavy artillery.

Comment: In addition to Joop, have a look at AspectJ.

Comment: Have a look at [field watchpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/types-of-breakpoints.html#d1582777e61). If breaking in the IDE is unsuitable you might want to try a [programmatic debugger](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/java-using-jpda-to-write-debugger.html).

Comment: As far as I understand AOP can only add logger before and after evaluating some method.. it cannot log inside the method. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AOP but I think following alternate is much better for just debugging your problem and having more control for just one time.

Maven downloads the dependencies in local .m2 directory
Go and decompile the dependency
modify as per your requirements
recompile the dependency and do "maven install" it will again install it in your local .m2
now build your maven project with maven offline mode, it won't be get replaced and you will see the logs etc which you have added during modification

Comment: Good idea, Jaffar, I do it via adding the modified classes to classpath before the original classes, but looks like our options are the easiest way..

Comment: @KutaBeach Which option?

Comment: Modifying the file and then inserting it into the project, via classpath as I did before, or via local Maven repository as you suggested.